# Calculating the Largest and smallest Letter through its ASCII value C#

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, windows

Hey im having some trouble with a school assignment. The issue is that I have a foreach loop searching through the userinput. It should display the Largest character or smallest, but when i insert Hello! it displays the largest value being !. The example states its supposed to be the lowercase o.
Here is my code. Forgive me if this looks messy, first time on this website, and this needs to be done quick.

This is all being done in a windows forum app in visual studio.

```
        if (UI_TB_UserInput.Text.Length > 0)
        {

            foreach (char c in UI_TB_UserInput.Text)
            {

                char min = UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0];//?
                char max = UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0];//?

                if (c < min)
                {

                    min = c;

                }
                if (c > max)
                {

                    max = c;

                }

                if (UI_RB_Min.Checked)
                {
                    UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = min.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = max.ToString();
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = "";//If not > 0 then display blank
        }
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to narrow the problem considerable, and provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Based on the little bit of code you posted here, it seems to me that all that's wrong is that your declaration and initialization of the `min` and `max` variables belong _outside_ the `foreach` loop (i.e. just before it). But without a complete and minimal example, it's impossible to say for sure whether there's anything else that might be wrong as well.

Comment: Declaration inside loops is indeed bad practice, but the reason this code is not working correctly is the initial assignment of min and max being inside the loop rather than before it.

Comment: Getting ASCII code is the important part of your question, seems like you missed it. :-)

Comment: @Arti Sadly, people use ASCII value when they are talking about `char`, a UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: @ChrisRollins Strongly disagree with that. Variables should have the smallest scope possible so we can understand their relevance. If your thinking is it is an inefficient use of space or time, try decompiling (or [disassembling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx)) code that the compiler has optimized. It won't look much like the code you write, unless you've totally defeated it by trying to do it's job.

Comment: @TomBlodget The question itself clearly said that he wants to [find the Largest and smallest Letter through its ASCII value C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39714768/1650891)

Comment: @Arti You are correct but the wording of the question is likely inaccurate, with "ASCII" being used like [Kleenex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_trademark).

Comment: You don't need to convert it to bytes. char is treated the same way as an integer type when compared in a conditional expression. The reason being, there's no other way to do it. At the end of the day you are comparing the binary. Again, the reason the code in the question doesn't work is because the initialization of the variables is inside the loop and thus every comparison is done against the first char rather than against what are meant to be the current min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `char min = UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0];` and `char max = UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0];`to **before** the loop starts. The way you have it, the min and max get set to the first character every iteration of the loop. Then it compares the character it is currently looking at to `UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0]` rather than what you intended to compare it to. You want this:

```
if (UI_TB_UserInput.Text.Length > 0)
    {
    char min = UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0];
    char max = UI_TB_UserInput.Text[0];

        foreach (char c in UI_TB_UserInput.Text)
        {
            if (c < min)
            {

                min = c;

            }
            if (c > max)
            {

                max = c;

            }

            if (UI_RB_Min.Checked)
            {
                UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = min.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = max.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = "";//If not > 0 then display blank
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why loop thru the string... Use the available features of arrays...

with a button_click on the form....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (UI_TB_UserInput.Text.Length > 0)
  {
    string inputString = UI_TB_UserInput.Text;
    char[] charArray = inputString.ToCharArray();
    Array.Sort(charArray); // array sorted from low to high
    Array.Reverse(charArray); // reverse order to get high to low
    UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = charArray[0].ToString();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed out the important part of the question **ASCII value**. You would have to get the `ASCII` values of the string first and then check its value. Here is the code working for me.

```
if (UI_TB_UserInput.Text.Length > 0)
{
    byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UI_TB_UserInput.Text);
    byte minByte = asciiBytes[0];
    byte maxByte = asciiBytes[0];
    foreach (byte i in asciiBytes)
    {
        if (i < minByte)
        {
            minByte = i;
        }
        if (i > maxByte)
        {
            maxByte = i;
        }

    }
    if (UI_RB_Min.Checked)
    {
        UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = ((char)minByte).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = ((char)maxByte).ToString();
    }
}
else
{
    UI_LB_MinMaxOutput.Text = "";//If not > 0 then display blank
}
```